# How to run all Mac traffic through Tor?

Tags: mac, socks

See title. Already tried this: https://maymay.net/blog/2013/12/26/one-minute-mac-tip-open-multiple-tor-circuits-in-the-new-torbrowserbundle-3-5-for-mac-os-x/. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Torify project. This support to route all traffic of a PC through Tor?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440792/how-do-i-install-torify-on-an-m1-mac

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure there are no leaks, IMO the best way would be to connect it to a [TOR Router](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/router-tor-raspberry-pi/).